# Doctrine recreates the same index

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When I run doctrine schema update, I am getting this weird queries that need to be executed but they are basically just redoing already done or not?

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql 


DROP INDEX idx_26d7e8feab772a3c ON notify;
CREATE INDEX IDX_217BEDC8AB772A3C ON notify (notifyUser_id);
DROP INDEX idx_26d7e8fea76ed395 ON notify;
CREATE INDEX IDX_217BEDC8A76ED395 ON notify (user_id);
DROP INDEX idx_26d7e8fe6bf700bd ON notify;
CREATE INDEX IDX_217BEDC86BF700BD ON notify (status_id);


    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.5.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.3.*@dev",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "~1.1@dev",
},
```

This behaviour stops me from updating doctrine schema with --force because there are foreign keys and I get this error:

```
[PDOException]                                                                        
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'IDX_A37CA197A76ED395': neede  
  d in a foreign key constraint
```

This started to happening probably after updating DB related vendors in past but I haven't notice it until now.

Answer (score 7):

@theapprenticecoder @Trki this problem can be solve by the command

```
$ app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --complete
```

which is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm you that this probably happened when you upgraded Doctrine Vendors.

This issue was fixed with the doctrine/dbal 2.5.1 version.

All you need to do is install the v2.5.1 doctrine/dbal dependency.
Then just do a "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" and your problem will be solved...

Comment: Updating dbal didn't work for me. Though I wasn't trying to force but dump-sql to see if recreation code was gone and it wasn't.